# Draw a shape over a high res image?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I want to be able to draw a line over a high resolution photo (e.g. 8megapixel image) in a specific place.

That is a simple enough thing, and there are many posts about that already but my problem is that the CGContext "drawing space" doesn't seem to be the same as the high res image.

I can draw the line and save an image, but my problem is with drawing the line in a specific location. My coordinate spaces seem to be different than each other. I think there must be a scale factor that I am missing or my understanding is just messed up.

So my question is:

How do I draw on to a image, that is "aspect fit" to the screen (but is much higher resolution) and have the drawing (in this case a line) be in the same position on the screen and the final full resolution composited image?

example image:
[image]

The red line is the line I am drawing. It should go from the center of the start target (theTarget) to the center of the end target (theEnd).

I have simplified my drawing function down for posting here, but i suspect it is my whole thinking/approach that is wrong.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!  
@IBOutlet weak var theTarget: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var theEnd: UIImageView!

var lineColor = UIColor.redColor()
var targetPos : CGPoint!
var endPos : CGPoint!
var originalImage : UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "reference.jpg")
    originalImage = imageView.image

    drawTheLine() 
}


func drawTheLine () {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(originalImage!.size);

    // Draw the original image as the background
    originalImage?.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0))

    // Pass 2: Draw the line on top of original image
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);

    targetPos = theTarget.frame.origin
    endPos = theEnd.frame.origin

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, targetPos.x, targetPos.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPos.x, endPos.y)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor.CGColor)
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}

@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Create new image

   let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage!, nil, nil, nil )
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x,
            y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

    //redraw the line
    drawTheLine()

    print("the start pos of the line is: ", theTarget.frame.origin, " and end pos is: ", theEnd.frame.origin)

}


}
```

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the output image, and perhaps one with the expected output? I may have an answer for you.

Comment: Added :) I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact problem a while ago, so I wrote a `UIImageView` extension that maps the image view's coordinates into the image coordinates, when the fill mode is `.ScaleAspectFit`.

```
extension UIImageView {

    func pointInAspectScaleFitImageCoordinates(point:CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

        if let img = image {

            let imageSize = img.size
            let imageViewSize = frame.size

            let imgRatio = imageSize.width/imageSize.height // The ratio of the image before scaling.
            let imgViewRatio = imageViewSize.width/imageViewSize.height // The ratio of the image view

            let ratio = (imgRatio > imgViewRatio) ? imageSize.width/imageViewSize.width:imageSize.height/imageViewSize.height // The ratio of the image before scaling to after scaling.

            let xOffset = (imageSize.width-(imageViewSize.width*ratio))*0.5 // The x-offset of the image on-screen (as it gets centered)
            let yOffset = (imageSize.height-(imageViewSize.height*ratio))*0.5 // The y-offset of the image on-screen (as it gets centered)

            let subImgOrigin = CGPoint(x: point.x*ratio, y: point.y*ratio); // The origin of the image (relative to the origin of the view)

            return CGPoint(x: subImgOrigin.x+xOffset, y: subImgOrigin.y+yOffset);
        }
        return CGPointZero
    }
}
```

You should be able to use this in your `drawTheLine` function quite easily:

```
func drawTheLine () {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(originalImage!.size);

    // Draw the original image as the background
    originalImage?.drawAtPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0))

    // Pass 2: Draw the line on top of original image
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);

    targetPos = imageView.pointInAspectScaleFitImageCoordinates(theTarget.frame.origin)
    endPos = imageView.pointInAspectScaleFitImageCoordinates(theEnd.frame.origin)

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, targetPos.x, targetPos.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, endPos.x, endPos.y)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor.CGColor)
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}
```